# Imagine I found a fast algorithm for prime factorization. What to do? Who to contact?

Tags: cryptography, confidentiality, nsa

I'm often playing around with prime numbers, just for fun. Imagine, I found an algorithm by accident that factorizes numbers into their prime parts exactly as fast as multiplicating them in the first place. I know this is extremly unlikely. But imagine I did. Imagine also, that it's easy to proof having some new kind of "mathematical paradigm" I found that's valid.

Now, as far as I understand that, that would have many consequences in cryptography.

So, what to do then? Just release the information in a mathematical journal and risks many many businesses worldwide who are suddenly open to attack? Or contact the NSA?

Who would be responsible for any action? And if anyone at all, which actions will they do?

Comment: *"I'm often playing around with prime numbers, just for fun. Imagine, I found an algorithm by accident that factorizes numbers into their prime parts..."* - this is about as likely as finding a *working* cancer therapy when just playing with a chemistry kit. If you really have the knowledge to find such thing then you very likely know at least one living math expert who can verify your findings and who know more experts and who will very likely know crypto experts who then know what to do. Could we please move to real-world questions again and close this one?

Comment: `...risks many many businesses worldwide who are suddenly open to attack? Or contact the NSA?` that seems like a false dichotomy. Publishing the information would at least give the businesses a chance to see what has happened.

Comment: Without going into the probability of one finding such an alghorithm by chance.... The NSA would likely be the last organisation I would contact.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that NSA will contact you first.

Answer (score 2):

#### First Steps

If you're worried about your work being stolen, I'd recommend publishing the hash of your findings in a few public places to ensure that you can prove that you were the original finder of the issue.  If you're just worried about the impact of your findings, you should be able to proceed with the advice below.

#### Then what?

I would start by contacting a mathematician to verify my findings.  Obviously you'd want one you trust, such as one that teaches at a university near you.  Alternatively, reach out to a well-known mathematics institute such as [The Clay Mathematics Institute](https://www.claymath.org/) [1], or a [well known cryptographer](https://www.ranker.com/list/notable-cryptographer_s%29/reference) who may be able to ensure that your findings are legitimate.

I would then work with whoever you pick, possibly in conjunction with the [IETF](https://www.ietf.org/contact/) to figure out a repair and disclosure timeline.

[1] - no affiliation, I just know them from the Millennium Problems

Comment: I wouldn't start with contacting a mathematician.  I would start with proving the algorithm works by factoring some of the unsolved [RSA primes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA_Factoring_Challenge).  The upshot would be A) proving your algorithm works without disclosing how it works and B) cashing in on some reward money.

Comment: I didn't know about those, thanks! (EDIT: Though it looks like the challenge has ended...)

Comment: The challenges have indeed ended. However, there are a _lot_ of ways you can get a _lot_ of money if you find an efficient classical prime factorization algorithm.